# Móvel para livros 3d em autolisp (lsp)

Tags: gráfico, lisp, autolisp

Estou a tentar fazer um armário para livros em autolisp através da subtração de caixas pequenas a uma maior.
Para além de não estar a conseguir, não sei como tornar o número de prateleiras uma variável para permitir a variedade das mesmas.

```lisp
(defun c:movel2 ()
(setq pontos2d (getvar "osmode"))
(setq pontos3d (getvar "3dosmode"))
(setvar "osmode" 0)
(setvar "3dosmode" 0)
(setq pt1 (getpoint "indique o ponto de insercao do movel : "))
(If (= nil
(setq comprimento (getreal " indique o comprimento do movel (em x):
")))
(setq comprimento 1.60))
(If (= nil
(setq largura (getreal "indique a largura do movel(em y): ")))
(setq largura 1.40))
(If (= nil
(setq altura (getreal "indique a altura do movel : (em z): ")))
(setq altura 2))
(If (= nil
(setq esp1 (getreal "indique a espessura do movel: ")))
(setq esp1 0.05))
(If (= nil
(setq gav (getpoint "indique a altura das gavetas do movel : "))
(setq gav 0.50))

(modelar)
(setvar "osmode" pontos2d)
(setvar "3dosmode" pontos3d)
(command "ucs" "")
(command "shade")
)
(defun modelar ()
(command "ucs" pt1 "")
(command "box" (list 0 0 altura))
(setq b1 (entlast))
(command "box" (list esp1 0 esp1) (list (-comprimento esp1) (-largura esp1) gav))
(setq b2 (entlast))
(command "subtract" b2 "" b1 "")
)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

este seria o objetivo

Comment: Benvindo ao StackOverflow em português! Favor utilizar a língua da plataforma.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: Como o esperado é um resultado visual poderia editar a pergunta e adicionar uma entrada para teste mais as imagens do resultado obtido e do resultado esperado? Seria bom informar qual o editor gráfico pois podem existir variações de nomenclatura e limitações de funções entre os editores.

Comment: Me desculpa mas isso é uma foto, para mim a pergunta perdeu o sentido. Quando comentei estava falando em desenho técnico em AutoCad ou clones. Remova a foto(não mais mexerei na pergunta) e novamente peço que adicione dados de entrada para teste(*valores que alimentam a função*), adicione imagem **cotada** do resultado que está obtendo e uma imagem **cotada** do resultado do espera,  poucos vão abrir o autocad o trivial é comparar visualmente o que está recebendo com que deseja receber e manipular a função em direção ao resultado.

Answer (score -3):

Associa-se valor a uma vari'avel com as funções
(set sym expr)      Sets the value of a quoted symbol name to an expression
Define o valor de um nome de símbolo entre aspas para uma expressão
e
(setq sym1 expr1 [sym2 expr2] ...)      Sets the value of a symbol or symbols to associated expressions
Define o valor de um símbolo ou símbolos para expressões associadas

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).